# C# - Convert byte[] to String in Windows 7 Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, arrays

Hi
I am trying to get device id of windows 7 phone using following code

```
 byte[] result = null;
 String id = null;
 object uniqueId;
 if (DeviceExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("DeviceUniqueId", out uniqueId))
     result = (byte[])uniqueId;
```

Problem is that I need this result in String. Can anyone tell me how to do this?
Best Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string myString = Convert.ToBase64String(result);
```

This function is available on the windows phone 7 platform

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(VS.95).aspx

And if you need the byte array again, just ask for it like this.

```
byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(myString);
```

edit: Curt provided the correct way to convert back to a byte array

Comment: FYI, in order to get the original bytes back from the Base 64 string you'll need to use Convert.FromBase64String(), not GetBytes() as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myBytes, 0, myBytes.Length);
```

I haven't checked but I suppose this method is available on Windows Phone.

Comment: When i do this, the result in debugger is shown in form of special characters.

Comment: This is the result i get after using the code you posted. Nʝ���Z�����ʻj�l"�

Comment: Is it specified somewhere that a "DeviceUniqueId" must be human-readable?